# Windows service not able to capture Login/Lock/Unlock in Win7

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

Windows service not able to capture Login/Lock/Unlock in Win7.
if any one knows the solution or any idea or approach, please help me out.
waiting for all of your positive response.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

Services are not notified of these events since they run in a different session from the interactive users. This has been true since Vista introduced what is known as Session 0 isolation.

Without knowing exactly what you are trying to achieve it's hard to give accurate advice. That said, a very common approach to this sort of issue is to run a standard app on the logged in users desktop that communicates with your service using, for example, a named pipe.

Comment: Thanks David for your time. I m trying the following event for this task, actually i want to log the entry when user login\logoff or lock\unlock.
SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch);